# Using component from parent module inside of child modules

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my Angular project, I am trying to use a component from a shared module where its child component is imported in the Dashboard module but facing this error.

1. If `app-send-email` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-send-email' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes = [
{ 
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
}]
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
    import { SendEmailComponent } from './shared/send-email.component';
    import { SharedDialogComponentModule } from '../shared/shared-dialog-component.module';
    @NgModule({
imports: [SharedDialogComponentModule],
      declarations: [ RecruiterSendEmailComponent ]
    });
```

**shared-dialog-component.module.ts**

```
import { EmailDialogComponent } from '../../dashboard/shared/template/dialog/email-dialog/email-dialog.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [EmailDialogComponent],
  entryComponents: [EmailDialogComponent],
  exports: [EmailDialogComponent]
})
```

**email-dialog.component.html**

```
<app-send-email></app-send-email>
```

Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to import the module `SharedDialogComponentModule`

```
import { SendEmailComponent } from './shared/send-email.component';
import { SharedDialogComponentModule } from '../shared/shared-dialog-component.module';
@NgModule({
  import: [ SharedDialogComponentModule ]
  declarations: [ RecruiterSendEmailComponent ]
});
```

Comment: Ya, I have added in the imports array as well still the same

Comment: @NikithaMunigala : I do not see any component for `app-send-email` . Can you confirm that you have declared this component inside   `SharedDialogComponentModule`